# Filter options according to optgroup label text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, html-select

I have one select box with a list of games and the other with filled with a list of consoles. Each game has the possibility to belong to a number of consoles. I'm looking to filter the second select box according to whichever game is selected in the first.

So for instance if I select a game like Forza Horizon that belongs to more than one console then the console select box would filter just those and hide the others.

Right now I have it setup where on a select event it captures the text value of the game. From there I figured to filter through their respective optgroup's label property, which is the console it belongs to. I just can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the other possible consoles it may belong to other than the selected option.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m178xpc3/2)**

```
<select class="game-select">
  <option value="">Select a game</option>
  <optgroup label="PS4"></optgroup>
    <option value="1">Forza Horizon 2</option>
    <option value="2">The Last of Us</option>
    <option value="3">Bioshock Infinite</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Xbox One">
    <option value="1">Forza Horizon</option>
    <option value="2">Halo</option>
    <option value="3">Bioshock Infinite</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select class="console-select">
  <option value="">Select a console</option>
  <option value="1">PS4</option>
  <option value="2">Xbox One</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var gameConsoles = $(".console-select").html();

  $(".game-select").on("change", function() {
    var game    = $(this).find("option:selected").text(),
        options = gameConsoles.filter().html(); // Not sure how to filter
    if (options) {
      $(".console-select").html(options);
    } else {
      $(".console-select").empty();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Selectize http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ it helps a lot when dealing with selects.

Comment: [is this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/m178xpc3/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2

You can do something like this

```
$(function () {
    var consoleSelect = $('.console-select'),
        gameConsoleOptions = $('.console-select option');

    $(".game-select").on("change", function () {
        var selectedGame = $(this).find("option:selected").data('game'), 
            games = [],
            selectedCategory = $(this).find("option:selected").closest('optgroup').attr('label');
        if (selectedGame) {
            games = $.makeArray($(this).find('option[data-game="' + selectedGame + '"]').map(function () {
                return $(this).closest('optgroup').attr('label');
            }));
        }

        if (games.length) {
            gameConsoleOptions.hide();
            gameConsoleOptions.filter(function (i, v) {
                return games.indexOf($(v).text()) != -1;
            }).show();
            consoleSelect.find('option:contains('+selectedCategory+')').prop('selected', 'selected');
        } else {
            gameConsoleOptions.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/m178xpc3/11/**

---

#### Update

I added a code to each game using the `data-*` attribute. 
For example the below two games have the same `data-game` attribute which can be used to figure out that these two are of the same category.

```
<option value="1" data-game="FH">Forza Horizon 2</option>
<option value="2" data-game="FH">Forza Horizon</option>
```

Complete example

```
<select class="game-select">
    <option value="">Select a game</option>
    <optgroup label="PS4">
        <option value="1" data-game="FH">Forza Horizon 2</option>
        <option value="2" data-game="LU">The Last of Us</option>
        <option value="3" data-game="BI">Bioshock Infinite</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Xbox One">
        <option value="1" data-game="FH">Forza Horizon</option>
        <option value="2" data-game="HA">Halo</option>
        <option value="3" data-game="BI">Bioshock Infinite</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<select class="console-select">
    <option value="">Select a console</option>
    <option value="1">PS4</option>
    <option value="2">Xbox One</option>
</select>
```

This is the script

```
$(function () {
    var gameConsoleOptions = $('.console-select option');

    $(".game-select").on("change", function () {
        var selectedGame = $(this).find("option:selected").data('game'), games = [];
        console.log(selectedGame);
        if (selectedGame) {
            games = $.makeArray($(this).find('option[data-game="' + selectedGame + '"]').map(function () {
                return $(this).closest('optgroup').attr('label');
            }));
        }
        console.log(games);
        if (games) {
            gameConsoleOptions.hide();
            gameConsoleOptions.filter(function (i, v) {
                return games.indexOf($(v).text()) != -1;
            }).show();
        } else {
            gameConsoleOptions.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/m178xpc3/10/**

---

You can do something like this

```
$(function () {
    var gameConsoleOptions = $('.console-select option');

    $(".game-select").on("change", function () {
        var label = $(this).find("option:selected").closest('optgroup').prop('label');
        if (label) {
            gameConsoleOptions.hide();
            gameConsoleOptions.filter(function (i, v) {
                return $(v).text() === label;
            }).show();
        }else{
            gameConsoleOptions.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/m178xpc3/5/**

Comment: Almost. It's just that for an option like `Forza Horizon` which belongs to both the `Xbox One` and `PS4` the options in the `.console-select` should have both both consoles present instead of one of the two.

Comment: That second fiddle seems to work but for some reason the `.console-select` select box doesn't move from the placeholder option once the `.game-select` is changed? Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. If `last of us` is selected `PS4` should also be selected?

Comment: Yeah. Pretty much whatever the selected value is other than the placeholder.

Comment: @CarlEdwards: Updated answer, please check now

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you wanted?

```js
$(".game-select").on("change", function() {
  var o = $('option:selected', $(this));
  if (!o.val()) {
    $('.game-select optgroup').show();
    $('.console-select option').show();
    return;
  }
  $('.console-select > option').hide();
  var a = $('option:contains("' + o.text() + '")').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == o.text();
  }).each(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var l = t.parent().attr('label');
    $('.console-select option:contains("' + l + '")').filter(function() {
      return l == $(this).text();
    }).show();
  });
});

$(".console-select").on("change", function() {
  var o = $('option:selected', $(this));
  if (!o.val()) {
    $('.game-select optgroup').show();
    $('.console-select option').show();
    return;
  }
  $('.game-select optgroup').hide();
  console.log($('.game-select optgroup[label="' + o.text() + '"]'));
  $('.game-select optgroup[label="' + o.text() + '"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="game-select">
  <option value="">Select a game</option>
  <optgroup label="PS4">
    <option value="c1">Forza Horizon 2</option>
    <option value="c2">The Last of Us</option>
    <option value="c3">Bioshock Infinite</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Xbox One">
    <option value="s1">Forza Horizon</option>
    <option value="s2">Halo</option>
    <option value="s3">Bioshock Infinite</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select class="console-select">
  <option value="">Select a console</option>
  <div>
    <option value="c">PS4</option>
    <option value="s">Xbox One</option>
  </div>
</select>
```

Comment: The only issue is that when I select a game that's exclusive to one console it still shows two options. So for example select the game, Last of Us. You'll see both Xbox One and PS4 in the select box when PS4 should be the only one there.

Comment: What's strange is that it retrieves the appropriate options but no longer auto selects on change for the second select box.

Comment: I modified snippet. Maybe not exactly what you want, but in general it should work. You can try it now and modify as you want in according to your task.

Answer (score 0):

The code should speak for itself but it all comes down to multiple jQuery filter functions and a clone of the set with options. One advice: Use data attributes instead of relying on the option element text. I updated the fiddle, see link below.

```
$(function() {
      var gameConsoles = $(".console-select");
      var consoleOptions = gameConsoles.find('option').clone();
      var gameSelect = $(".game-select").on("change", function() {
          var game = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
          var filteredOptions = $();
          gameSelect.find('optgroup').filter(function() {
              return $(this).find('option').filter(function() {
                  return $(this).text() == game;
              }).length;
          }).each(function () {
              var label = $(this).attr('label');
              filteredOptions = filteredOptions.add(consoleOptions.filter(function() {
                  return $(this).text() == label;
              }));
           });
          gameConsoles.html(filteredOptions);
  });
});
```

[Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/m178xpc3/9/)